# How should I do QA automation for the demo application on the Samsung Tizen Smart TV using Appium?

Tags: testing, automation, appium, tizen, samsung

I have a Samsung T4 Tizen Series real smart device. I want to write a sample application for automation testing on it, so how to do that using Appium or any similar library or framework tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Appium is not yet supported on Samsung TV due to security policies.

https://developer.samsung.com/tizen/Smart-TV/FAQ/Smart-TV/Known-issue-2018.html

Comment: Thanks for the Update @flyofsky, so do you have any suggestions for that how I can do Automation using any tools and lib. ?